# What is the default keyboard layout for Fable 3 on the PC?

Tags: pc, fable-3

I managed to find the combat settings, and figure out how to change those, but I'm still looking for ways to access, for example, the main menu from the keyboard. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is in the [manual page 7](http://cdn.steampowered.com/Manuals/105400/FableIII_GFW_EN_UK.PDF?t=1306254708):

[image: Fable 3 Keyboard default configuration]